# How to transform Microsoft Graph API query with expand=extensions to SDK code

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am transforming from Graph API to Graph SDK. How can I transform this API call?

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/XXX/calendarView?startDateTime=YYY&endDateTime=ZZZ&$expand=extensions($filter=id eq 'NAME')
```

Expand part is missing. How should I add *Expand = ???* or do it somehow with Filter or Select?

```
var ret = await graphClient.Users[XXX].CalendarView.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
            {
                requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.StartDateTime = YYY;
                requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.EndDateTime = ZZZ;
            });
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: Which version of SDK do you use?

Comment: In 5.12 I see Expand property: `requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = new string[] { "extensions($filter=id+eq+'NAME')" };`

Comment: @user2250152 ah it didnt works before. Probably my typo in string. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @user2250152. I made a typo. Solution is as follows:

```
requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = new string[] 
{ 
    "extensions($filter=id+eq+'NAME')" 
};
```